# Asking two questions, one of which implies the other

Tags: discussion

I have two statements, A and B, and I want to ask on MO whether they are true.  They are not obviously related, but I have a (simple) argument to show that A implies B.    Should I:

- Ask about both in a single question, even though they are apparently unrelated?  (I would include an explanation of why A implies B.)
- Ask two separate questions, including in each one a mention of the implication and link to the other?

To address Gil Kalai's comment: In this particular case, each question is quite short: a sentence or two for the statement, plus perhaps a paragraph of motivation.  I personally think each one is independently interesting.

Comment: It depends how long they are and to what extent A is of independent interest. Anyway the default would be to ask a single question.

Comment: @GilKalai, thanks.  I edited to address this.

Comment: Ask a single question and show why A implies B.

Comment: Ask about A, and include a synopsis of A implies B, unless it is short enough to include a complete version.  Also include a motivation for B, and how (B and not A) would be of interest.  If the result is not too long, you might also indicate how you came across the simple argument.  Gerhard "You Can Partition It Later" Paseman, 2013.11.12

Comment: I've gone ahead and asked it as [one question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/148691/meager-subspaces-of-a-banach-space-and-weak-convergence).

Comment: ...neither of which I can answer.